# Populating function's array via JSON

Tags: ajax, jquery-ui, timeline

I am using this timeline plug-in as a base for my own: http://www.jqueryscript.net/other/Create-A-Simple-Vertical-Timeline-with-jQuery-CSS.html

The code I'm trying to change is step 3. Create events for the timeline using Javascript array object.

My code:
(note that `#events` is my timeline container for all the data)

```
$(function() {          

  $.ajax({
    url: url,
    type: 'get',
    dataType: 'json',
    async: false,
    success: function(data) {

        for (i = 0; i < data.timeline.length; i++) {
            event = data.timeline[i];

            numDate = event.shortdate;
            txtTitle = event.longdate;
            eventType = event.category;
            eventDesc = event.description;
        
            dataInfo = '{ date: new Date(' + numDate + '), type: "' + eventType + '", title: "' + txtTitle + '", description: "' + eventDesc + '" }';
            
            dataArray.push(dataInfo);

        }
            
    }
  });

  $('#events').timeline({
    data: dataArray,
    height: 800 // in pixel
  });
```

However, this is causing an error in the function that generates the timeline:

> TypeError: firstDate is undefined
>
> var tempDate = new Date(firstDate.getTime());

I'm thinking that perhaps something goofy is going on with my `dataInfo` variable. Any tips would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your biggest issue is that you're creating an array of strings, but the plugin expects an array of objects (not JSON, but an actual array of objects).

```
$(function () {
    var dataArray = [];

    $.ajax({
        url: url,
        type: 'get',
        dataType: 'json',
        async: false,
        success: function (data) {
            for (i = 0; i < data.timeline.length; i++) {
                event = data.timeline[i];

                dataArray.push({
                    date: new Date(event.shortdate),
                    type: event.category,
                    title: event.longdate,
                    description: event.description
                });
            }
        }
    });

    $('#events').timeline({
        data: dataArray,
        height: 800 // in pixel
    });
});
```

Again, even if the plugin did want JSON (which is a string) as opposed to an array of objects, you weren't providing it with that either--you were proving an array of strings, each of which were an attempt at JSON serializing some data.

Also, if you ever do need to produce JSON, don't do it manually with string concatenation. Create an actual data structure, then `JSON.stringify()` it.

Finally, you need to ensure that your `shortdate` property on the returned data is something which `Date` can use to accurately create the represented date.

Comment: +1 Well explained @JAAulde; I admittedly wasn't clear on what the plug-in was expecting as an input; your solution certainly seems more accurate.

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately the plug-in doesn't look to be all that well documented (as an aside, consider [this one](https://github.com/technotarek/timeliner) perhaps?) but based on just the article & your sample, the issue is likely in your `dataInfo` as you suspect.

You're not actually providing a valid Date object for the value of the `date` property; my guess is it should be this:

```
numDate = new Date(event.shortdate);
...
dataInfo = '{ date:' + numDate + ', type: "' + eventType + '", title: "' + txtTitle + '", description: "' + eventDesc + '" }';
```

EDIT: Look to JAAulde's answer for the correct way to do this.

Comment: Concatenating a `Date` instance to a string will implicitly call `toString` during the resulting cast. That the OP is building a string at all is the real issue.

Comment: I appreciate the alternate timeline suggestion - will check it out for sure!